# Can you remove a commit made to a branch on AWS code commit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, versioning

I know of git rebase but don't know if it can be used with AWS code commit?
Or if there's any other method of removing a commit to revert back to before it was made and merged?

Answer (score 2):

Simplest answer is to just revert the commit.  AWS Code Commit is standard Git and will support everything Git allows you to do.

I.e. find commit hash:

```
git log -n1
commit 444c954e458cc446e2a7a1f2659adf71bdf55580 (HEAD -> my-branch, origin/my-branch)
```

Then do the revert:

```
git revert 444c954e458cc446e2a7a1f2659adf71bdf55580
git push
```

It'll revert your repo to whatever state it would be without that specific commit.  Note that if you have other commits that modified the same files afterward, you will have a merge conflict and will have to fix them manually.